# Православное и Католическое (Рождество) - строчная или заглавная?

Tags: орфография

С какой буквы пишутся слова "православное" и "католическое" в данном случае?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Со строчной. Сравните например со фразой *пушкинский и лермонтовский "Пророк"*. Православное и католическое, здесь обычное определение, а не часть имени собственного, так что 25 декабря христиане всего мира будут отмечать Рождество Христово. Православные Рождество будут отмечать - православное, а католики - католическое.